# Auth0 with React PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

How to add Auth0 with React PropTypes?

index.js

```
import App from '../components/App';
import WelcomeRoute from './Welcome';
import SettingsRoute from './Settings';
import CampaignRoute from './Campaign';

export default {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  indexRoute: WelcomeRoute,
  childRoutes: [
    SettingsRoute,
    CampaignRoute
  ]
};
```

App.js

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Header from '../../components/Header';
import MessagesStack from '../../components/MessagesStack'

const App = ({children}) => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <section className="ui main container">
      <MessagesStack />
      {children}
    </section>
  </div>
);

App.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
};

export default App;
```

The sample from Auth0 show this:

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import {requireAuth} from '../auth';
import Site from './Site';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import EditProfile from './EditProfile';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route component={Site}>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route onEnter={requireAuth}>
            {/* Place all authenticated routes here */}
            <Route path="/profile/edit" component={EditProfile} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your component depends on Auth0 user profile and/or AuthService you could do following

```
import React, { PropTypes as T } from 'react'
...
import AuthService from 'utils/AuthService'
...

export class ProfileEdit extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    profile: T.object,
    auth: T.instanceOf(AuthService)
  }

.
.
.
}
```

Here is the complete sample for it https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-sample/blob/master/04-User-Profile
and specifically here you can see how PropTypes is used with respect to Auth0 user profile and AuthService https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-sample/blob/master/04-User-Profile/src/components/Profile/ProfileEdit.js#L8